# Windows 10 image too large for Brasero to burn. How can I get around this?

Tags: boot, dvd, burning

I have just downloaded a Windows10 image:

```
$ du --bytes Win10_1709_German_x64.iso
4710961152  Win10_1709_German_x64.iso
```

It is slightly too large to burn it to a dvd (4.7gb) with [Brasero](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Brasero/).

[image: brasero dialog data size is too large for the disc]

Is there a way to force burning the disc, using some additional space on the disc or shrinking the iso?

Comment: actually no duplicate as I primarily wanted to burn it to disk but I will try your suggestion

Comment: Try looking at the file with `du -h Win10_1709_German_x64.iso`

Comment: It will only output the shortcutted size of **4.4G**. As *every byte* here matters, I did not use the human option.

Comment: Make a bootable USB-drive instead.  Installs much faster too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use K3B as brasero doesn't appear to support overburn. Go to Settings->Advanced and check the allow overburn box as shown below:

[image]

k3b is available for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu in the Universe repository. To obtain it First [enable Universe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) then issue the following commands in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install k3b
```

or use your favorite package manager.

Comment: overburning is the solution. Thank you. Unfortunately not available to brasero.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to burn the iso using `growisofs` from the package `dvd+rw-tools`:

```
 $ growisofs -overburn --dvd-compat -Z /dev/sr0=Win10_1709_German_x64.iso 
Executing 'builtin_dd if=Win10_1709_German_x64.iso of=/dev/sr0 obs=32k seek=0'
:-( /dev/sr0: 2298496 blocks are free, 2300274 to be written!
:-! ignoring...
/dev/sr0: "Current Write Speed" is 16.4x1352KBps.
    1277952/4707319808 ( 0.0%) @0.0x, remaining 306:52 RBU 100.0% UBU   5.0%
(...)
 4706074624/4707319808 (100.0%) @0.3x, remaining 0:00 RBU  14.6% UBU  99.4%
:-[ WRITE@LBA=231020h failed with SK=5h/INVALID ADDRESS FOR WRITE]: Invalid argument
:-( write failed: Invalid argument
/dev/sr0: flushing cache
/dev/sr0: updating RMA
/dev/sr0: closing disc
/dev/sr0: reloading tray
```

It will expectedly throw out some errors but installing Windows 10 from this disc was successful.

Comment: This works without having to install additional software, unlike the selected answer.